# What's the difference between 入(root) and 人 (men)

Tags: difference

http://zhongwen.com/d/164/x74.htm

This character looks like 人 alot.

That website says that it's the character of roots descending into earth

I search for root in mgdb and can't find it.

I search for 入 and I found this
https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=1&wdqt=ru%0D%0A

What's the difference between 入and人?
They look almost the same to me. When inside other pics how do I know which one is which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has a page [*Easily confused Chinese characters*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Easily_confused_Chinese_characters) (there's quite a few of these), and it describes 人 vs. 入 as follows:

> - Notes: added hook at top of second character.
> - In some print fonts, characters have symmetric legs, and are easily confused; in handwriting, they are further distinguished by having asymetric legs: 入 has a shorted left leg and looks like λ (lambda), while 人 has a shorter right leg and looks like a backwards λ.

It's fonts that make these two characters difficult to distinguish.  Here are animations from the [人](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%BA) and [入](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%A5) Wiktionary pages for how to handwrite them:

[image][image]

Their meanings are totally different, so it's also possible to infer the correct character from the surrounding material.  E.g. 中国人 ("Chinese person") vs. 收入 ("income").

Answer (score 3):

You can put them side by side on [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=1&wdqt=%E5%85%A5%E4%BA%BA%0D%0A):

> [image]

Where is the difference? Have a look:

> [image]

You can see on the two circled parts that the right side of `入` actually slants a little to the left, where as `人` is generally left is left and right is right.

Comment: how do you put them side by side?

Comment: @user4951 You can click the link I left above in the answer to MDBG and have a look. All I did was put the two characters “入人” into the search bar for query.